# d3.js multiple series line chart - color of each series

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With a multiple series line chart D3.js is it possible to manually specify the colour of each line?

**data.csv**

```
source_,track_index,alt,dist
series1,xxx,100,100
series1,xxx,200,200
series2,xxx,100,100
series2,xxx,200,200
```

**.html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
  body { font: 12px Arial;}
  path {stroke: steelblue;stroke-width: 2;fill: none;}
  .axis path,.axis line {fill: none;stroke: grey;stroke-width: 1;shape-rendering: crispEdges;}
  .line {fill: none;stroke: steelblue;stroke-width: 1.5px;}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right,height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse; // Parse the date / time
var color = d3.scale.category10();

var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0,width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
.orient("left").ticks(5);

var alt_line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.dist_); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.alt_); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("/data.csv", function(error, data) {

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.dist_ = d.dist;
    d.alt_ = d.alt;
});

x.domain([0, 30]); 
y.domain([0, 3000]); 

var dataNest = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) {return d.source_;})
.entries(data);

dataNest.forEach(function(d) { 
   svg.append("path")
   .attr("class", "line")
   .attr("d", alt_line(d.values)); 
});

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis);

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "preferred method"? It would usually depend on the application how the colour for a line is determined.

Comment: The "stock" mbostock [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) does it in code using a [color scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category10).  Copying how Mike Bostock does things is about as close as you can get to a "preferred method".  If you need an example of how to integrate with your code, comment back...

Comment: By preferred method I meant can you specify a color manually (via hex or RGB) . The example given on the mbostock page structures the data quite differently (date, series1 value, series2 value) vs the data.csv structure above. I've edited the question to hopefully make it more clear. Thanks for the replies.